# RegEx - avoid matching a word ending with a specific character

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex (regexp) that will avoid matching words ending with '@', '-', '!', ':' and '>'

The rules are as follows - the name should begin with @ can have any character after it except the ones above.
So in the following strings:
'zhsvfghzfajhuib@Bobbie?skvshvfhj!G!' - @Bobbie? will match
'768huehfvwkjv@Lana97958749ndgjhb!G!' - @Lana9 will match
',vbfnhytjnh@Sammie-sjvjhsvfjj!G!kjdbdjb' - @Sammie- will NOT match, because the character after the name is in the above range.

My latest attempt is : @(?[A-Za-z]+)[^@-!:>] but all it did was to remove the last character and still matched.

I tried:

- adding another character in the search @(?[A-Za-z]+).[^@-!:>] but the search just moved to the next character.
- adding a word boundary @(?[A-Za-z]+)\b[^@-!:>] which help in some cases but not all

Comment: Why would any of the examples be a match when there are exclamation marks at the end of the first two examples? Also, why @Lana9 and not @Lana97958749ndgjhb!G!'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If supported, you can use an [atomic group](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#atomic):

```
@(?>(?<name>[A-Za-z]+))[^@\-!:>]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gXGwvQ/1)

Another option is using a positive lookahead with a capture group and a backreference as there is [no backtracking in lookarounds](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#atomic):

```
@(?=([A-Za-z]+))\1[^@\-!:>]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xXUhHY/1)